# Query for multiple count values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

```
SELECT  cm.commenter_id,
        cm.comment,
        m.id,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS r_count
            FROM comments
            GROUP BY comments.commenter_id
        ) AS count,
        m.display_name
FROM    comments cm
        INNER JOIN members m
            ON cm.commenter_id = m.id
```

From this query I want to get the display_name for the person with the highest count of comments. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.id, m.display_name, COUNT(*) totalComments
FROM    comments cm
        INNER JOIN members m
            ON cm.commenter_id = m.id
GROUP   BY m.id, m.display_name
HAVING  COUNT(*) =
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCount
        FROM    Comments
        GROUP   BY  commenter_id
        ORDER   BY totalCount DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1666/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with duplicates*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36025/1)

Comment: mind explaining HAVING COUNT(*) line to me? never really used it like that before

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*)` works like a `WHERE` clause. But the main difference is that `HAVING` supports aggregate functions just like `MAX, MIN, SUM, etc..` while `WHERE` won't.

Comment: Thanks, also this works within this scope, but I should have posted more of the query which it is nested in. Throwing an error now

Comment: Oh nevermind, it was my mistake had left out a column reference. Thanks again @JW.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is just to sort your query and take the first row:

```
SELECT  cm.commenter_id,
        cm.comment,
        m.id,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS r_count
            FROM comments
            GROUP BY comments.commenter_id
        ) AS count,
        m.display_name
FROM    comments cm
        INNER JOIN members m
            ON cm.commenter_id = m.id
order by count desc
limit 1
```